# Looking to see if a column of long strings contains any item from a list of shorter strings

Tags: sql, string, join, google-bigquery

I have a column of long constructed strings. Somewhere in these strings (not always in the same location) there should be at least 1 portion that matches some item in a list I want to join on. The string portion im looking for has underscores on either side.
i.e.

```
Id   LongString
1    asd_Name1_af_2
2    asd_asd_Name2_3
3    wou_do_Name3_5_123

The list of potential matches would look like 
PotentialNames
Name1
Name2

The end result I am looking for is 
Id   LongString          PotentialNames
1    asd_Name1_af_2      Name1
2    asd_asd_Name2_3     Name2
3    wou_do_Name3_5_123  Null
```

I have tried two things

1. doing a partial string lookup
   (i.e. JOIN PotentialNames b ON  a.LongString LIKE concat('%\*',b.PotentialNames ,'\*%' )
   But I want to also include the case where there is no match or LongString is blank
2. splitting the LongString (SPLIT(LongString , '_')), but I then can't join with the given "array"